# How to show the item information listed in a GridView in the Ajax ModalPopUp Extender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am developing a simple intranet registration system for my department in the company. The available events will be listed in a GridView and the first column that shows the event title will be as a link button. What I want now is the following:

When the user clicks on one of these events title, a popup window will be displayed with showing the information of event which is already existed in the GridView with a Register Button. I am AjaxToolKit ModalPopUp Extender. I did almost everything but I don't know how to show the information of that event in the ModalPopUp.

**Could you please help me in this?**

My Code-Behind (C#):

```
protected void lnkTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //to get the GridViewRow from the sender, so we can get the datakey we need
    GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)sender)).NamingContainer;
    HiddenField1.Value = ListOfAvailableEvents_GrivView.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

    //show the modalPopUp
    modalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

My ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ListOfAvailableEvents_GrivView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="generaltext" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' OnClick="lnkTitle_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDateTime" HeaderText="Start Date & Time" SortExpression="StartDateTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDateTime" HeaderText="End Date & Time" SortExpression="EndDateTime" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="complete" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnModalPopUp" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnModalPopUp"
    PopupControlID="pnlPopUp" BackgroundCssClass="popUpStyle" PopupDragHandleControlID="panelDragHandle"
    OkControlID="OKButton">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopUp" runat="server" CssClass="popUpStyle">
    <asp:Button ID="confirmButton" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="btnSendConfirmationEmail_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PM_RegistrationSysDBConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT     ID, Title, Description, Location, StartDateTime, EndDateTime
                    FROM         dbo.Events
                    WHERE     (IsActive = 1)
                    ORDER BY ID DESC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

FYI, I have the following table in my database which I am binding it to the GridView:

```
Events Table: ID, Title, Description, Location, StartDateTime, EndDateTime
```

Please note I don't want to show the ID with the other information in the GridView

Comment: why are you trying to show a hidden field I think it would be more esier and precise if you would populate the modal popup extender from the codebehind with the information based on the row selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are couple of links that show a good tutorial and in my opinion would help you to achive what you want without using code-behind just using the client side so you can avoid the page refresh as user click the linkbutton

http://technico.qnownow.com/using-ajax-modal-popup-extender-asp-net-gridview-control/

http://shibashishdotnetocean.blogspot.com/2011/12/modalpopupextender-in-gridview.html

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=212

http://kishor-naik-dotnet.blogspot.com/2011/10/ajax-modalpopupextender-in-gridview.html